# What's the format value from the HWND returned from CreateWindow()?

Tags: windows, winapi, hwnd

Is this a memory address ranging to (theorically) 2^32-1 on 32-bit machine?
The reason I'd like to know that is I'm trying to somehow associate a HWND returned by CreateWindow() to a class instance, so in order to know how properly store that HWND value, I need to know what's the values like, so I can see what can fit better, AA array, linked list with hash table, etc.

Comment: The HWND is an opaque value. IOW, you can know nothing about it other than the fact that it's a window handle. The internal structure is not documented by MS because it's not supposed to be used as anything but a window handle.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/relationship-between-a-cpp-window-object-and-an-hwnd?view=msvc-160

Comment: if your formal ask for format - as general knowledge but not for usage - low 16 bits of `HWND` used as index in windows handle table. the next 16 bits used as reuse index - when a cell is used for the first time this index is 1. when this cell is reused, the index is increased by 1. and so on

Comment: *associate a HWND returned by CreateWindow() to a class instance* - for this `GWLP_USERDATA` used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation for MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/relationship-between-a-cpp-window-object-and-an-hwnd?view=msvc-160) (to avoid confusion: this is documentation where `CWnd` and "window *object*" in the article is a C++ class in **your** program, not `USER32`):

> The Windows window, on the other hand, [**is an opaque handle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) to an internal Windows data structure that corresponds to a window and consumes system resources when present.

Opaque handles must be treated as "black boxes" or *atomic blobs* that must not be altered and likely won't reveal any useful information through introspection either.

Also, see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)

Answer (score 2):

To store a value you need to know its type only. As documented under [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), an `HWND` is a type alias for a `HANDLE`, which is a type alias for `PVOID`, which in turn is a type alias for `void*`.

In other words: An `HWND` is a pointer to unknown data. It's pointer-sized and trivially copy-able.